# compiled btrfs into kernel: even as root: could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock: Permission denied

Tags: pi-2, linux, permissions

I have installed the latest raspbian on `/dev/sda1`, root filesystem is btrfs. So I had to recompile the kernel and compile the btrfs module into the kernel. For that, I used the latest `raspberrypi/linux` git (4.4.8), following exactly what was said [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md).

Now, everything seems to work, except for two things:

- it fails to run "Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown" during boot
- I cannot run any package manager, be it apt-get, dpkg, or aptitude. `apt-get update` just fails with

  ```
  E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
  E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
  E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
  E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
  ```

  which is the only output.

I did search the internet and read just about everything I could find. But almost all the answers talk about running as root. So, no:

- I did not forget `sudo`, I also tried logging in as root or doing `sudo bash`, but it all makes no difference.
- I deleted all the `lock` files under `/var`, no success.
- There are no other processes running. The lock files stay deleted until I execute `apt-get update` again, which recreates them and then it fails again :(

And I installed both, Ubuntu as well as Raspbian - same problem.

This has got to do with my kernel since everything else is unmodified. But I am lost now. How can I debug this problem? Which kernel config option did I forget or break?

I looked at the process with `strace` and got

```
open("/var/lib/dpkg/lock", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOFOLLOW, 0640) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl64(4, F_SETLK64, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}, 0x...) = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)
```

The only thing I am wondering about is the `fcntl64`? Why 64?

Comment: 64 bit cpu. I guess you don't have that on the pi-2.

Comment: @ott `strace` reports [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).   They are glue between userland and the kernel, and that one obviously ran.  Anyway, if the kernel or native library had been compiled 64-bit, the whole system would not work at all (i.e., this is just a coincidence in the name of the call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh no! Days of debugging wasted, but I finally found it: I disabled `CONFIG_FILE_LOCKING` (Enable POSIX file locking API), an option you will only see if `CONFIG_EXPERT` is set (which I usually don't set, but the raspberry config has it). It is needed for any locking, not just NFS.